# How to get the User Principal Name for logged in user using liquid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, liquid, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I am trying to find the `User Principal Name` of the logged in user in MSFT PowerPages and Power Portals but I can't find the correct property.

I can find `{{user.fullname}}` and other properties but not the UPN of the user or the External Identity of the contact which I also cannot find.

How can I find the property name for UPN and/or External Identity of the contact?